# Is there any way to refer to a Vue variable from another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to, upon a click on a button, reflect the value returned by that function to another component's value. For example, in this case I have a "Choose" button which when pressed opens a dialog. Once a folder is selected within that dialog, I want the variable tied to the input to be updated.

Right now what I am doing is using a custom data-destination attribute that I read within the openPickerDialog, then I set the variable to the value returned by the picker dialog. I am trying to make my function as general as possible so that I can reuse it. Is there a better way to achieve what I want with Vue? Something built-in?

```html
<div class='input-group align-items-end'>
  <input :id='destinationFolder' class='form-control shadow-none' type='text' v-model='destinationFolder'/>
  <span class='input-group-btn ml-2'>
    <button @click='openPickerDialog' class='btn btn-choose shadow-none' data-destination='destinationFolder' data-dialog='openDirectory' type='button'>Choose</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

```js
openPickerDialog({target}) {
  window.api
      .send('openDialog', options)
      .then((results) => {
        if (results !== null) {
          this.$data[target.dataset.destination] = results[0]
        }
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(e)
      })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried Vuex for global state management?
So you can refer states of other components.

Comment: I certainly have heard about it but the thing is, I will have these same variables for multiple components and they will have their own different values. I don't really see how Vuex could help me here.